# Multiple Javascript variables with the same value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.visibilityEnabled = 'Disabled';
$scope.invertEnabled = 'Disabled';
$scope.weightEnabled = 'Disabled';
$scope.saturationEnabled = 'Disabled'
```

I have the above Javascript variables, would it be possible to simplify them down at all and make them efficient?

Comment: what do you feel is the problem?

Comment: @sahbeewah Somehow I feel this could be simplified down as all the keys use the same value...

Comment: make that value into a separate variable and then assign that variable to your elements. That way if you need to edit the value you'll do it from one single place.

Comment: If the variables represent different things then, no, you can't "simplify" the variables themselves - and if the variables represent one thing, why have separate variables? As far as "efficiency": there is *no* problem with the above code, although you could reduce the number of repeated values for (possibly) "tidier code".

Comment: Good job to the person that down voted this question when it clearly has an answer - which was accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work also in Javascript

```
 $scope.visibilityEnabled = 
 $scope.invertEnabled = 
 $scope.weightEnabled = 
 $scope.saturationEnabled = 'Disabled';
```

Comment: I was typing the exact same thing. Arghhh.

Answer (score 0):

You could fairly simply change the values of all of the variables within your script to be the same name, but it wouldn't really make it any more efficient.  It appears that the variables are configuration values, so there is really no reason to do anything with them except change the values to modify the behaviour of the script.

If you're determined that there will be only one variable, use a find and replace editor, but it won't make it more efficient.